# Gradient Operator in Vector Spherical Harmonic Basis

Tags: vector-fields, continuum-mechanics, spherical-harmonics

The vector spherical harmonic basis (vector generalization to the scalar valued spherical harmonics) is a convenient spectral basis for problems involving vector fields with spherical symmetry ([link to wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics)).

If I have an expression of the form $$Z = \vec{A} : \nabla \vec{v}$$ where $Z$ is a scalar field, $\vec{A}$ is a rank two tensor and $\vec{v}$ is a vector field all in spherical polar coordinates, and I have to rewrite it in the vector spherical harmonic basis. How does the gradient operator translate? Are there nice properties like for [divergence or curl](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/pubs/publist/preprints/2006/ivers-29.pdf)?

(here the colon operator ":" represents the double dot product defined as $A:B = A_{ij}B_{ji}$)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the colon notation you're using. What does that mean? Is it a dot product (then use \cdot) -- or rather is it the *action* of $\vec{A}$ on grad-$v$? Second, is $\vec{B}$ in the paragraph below the definition of $Z$ supposed to be $\vec{A}$?

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question to include the definition of the : operator (double dot product $A:B = A_{ij}B_{ji}$) and fix the typo (should be $\vec{A}$) as you have pointed out.

Comment: Are you asking how to compute the gradient in spherical coordinates?

Comment: If that's the case, you can check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3265762/144053) in Math.SE

Comment: @nicoguaro I want to compute it in the vector spherical harmonic basis, where the basis is defined as in the wiki article above

Comment: I am not sure that the gradient operator is diagonalizable so you can express it in that basis in a simple manner

Comment: What do you mean by "gradient operator being diagonalizable"? Isn't the gradient operator on a rank 1 tensor also a rank 1 tensor? Is there some other way of thinking about the gradient operator?